# Nested for loop inside print function to print a specific pattern in python

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I'm using the following single line of python code to print out a specific pattern which I showed at the bottom.

> My code:
>
> ```py
> print(*[a, b, for a in range(5): for b in range(3)], sep='\n')
> ```

After executing the above code, I'm getting an `invalid syntax` error but I could not find any syntax error there.

> Error:
>
> ```py
> Getting error : SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

> My desired output as follow:
>
> ```py
> 1 1  
> 1 2  
> 1 3  
> 1 4  
> 2 1  
> 2 2  
> 2 3  
> 2 4
> ```

How can I print this pattern in a single line of code?

I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: As of now, answers provide only solutions, not explanations. So: **Why syntax error?** List comprehension doesn't allow 1) tuples to be without parentheses (because of commas that human may interpret wrongly), 2) commas and colons in strange places (before/after for, here: comma between b and for, colon between two fors). This would make it: `print(*[(a, b) for a in range(5) for b in range(3)], sep='\n')` Of course that only solves the error, not the formatting - but the string formatting was already explained by others. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for:

```
print(*[f'{a} {b}' for a in range(5) for b in range(3)], sep='\n')
```

> 0 0
>
> 0 1
>
> 0 2
>
> 1 0
>
> 1 1
>
> 1 2
>
> ...

Comment: f'{a} {b}' would you please elaborate these part?

Comment: @KittoMi this is a python f-string, this is like a string but everything put between `{}` is evaluated e.g. `print(f'1+2={1 + 2}')` prints '1+2=3'

Comment: *f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6, not 3.7

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that other answers don't have into account is that, in order to have the pattern that you are looking for, range should start at 1 and a and b should change places.

```
print(*["{} {}".format(a,b) for a in range(1, 3) for b in range(1, 5)], sep='\n')
```

Comment: List comprehensions are for creating a list. Not for iterating a call to print.

Comment: You are right. I edited the answer. It works anyway, but it is cleaner this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have made two syntax errors in your list comprehension

In a list comprehension the for loop is not an expression  so you don't write the colon`:`.

You want to store a string in the list comprehension. The expression that is stored by the list comprehension is not part of the print function. There are multiple ways of constructing the string. In this case f-strings are a good solution.

The correct syntax is

```
print(*[f"{a} {b}") for a in range(5) for b in range(3)], sep='\n')
```

If a list comprehension becomes too long, i tend to split it over multiple lines.

```
data = [
    f"{a} {b}"
    for a in range(5)
    for b in range(3)
]
print(*data, sep="\n")
```